# Winter '16 problem with navigateToUrl('/p/process/Submit?

Tags: javascript

We have a custom JavaScript [Submit for Approval] button that starts with

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/21.0/connection.js")}.
```

You get the modal dialog asking if you want to continue (good) but when you click ok, it then pops this error

> "Choose Approver: We need to confirm that your request is valid.
>   Please repeat your last action."

The code ends with this which seems to cause the error but this works fine in Production and always use to work in sandbox.

```
navigateToUrl( '/p/process/Submit?retURL=%2Fa13Q0000000HBFk&id={!SVMXC__Service_Contract__c.Id}','DETAIL','submit');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an intentional change as part of Winter 16 release, to over come this you may need to use REST API to submit the approval or use apex code

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000229821&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I just developed to solve this problem:

```
if ((Modal.confirm && Modal.confirm('Once you escalate this Report, you must recall the approval before you can edit it. Continue?')) || (!Modal.confirm && window.confirm('Once you submit this Report, you must recall the approval before you can edit it. Continue?'))) 
{
////////////////////////////////////////// 
var sUrlFull = '{!$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_350}';
var sUrl = sUrlFull.substring(0, sUrlFull.indexOf('.com'));

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open( "POST", sUrl+".com/services/data/v30.0/process/approvals/", false); 

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + "{!$Api.Session_Id}");

var strBodyJson = '{"requests" : [{"actionType": "Submit", "contextActorId": "{!$User.Id}", "contextId": "{!YOURRECORD.Id}", "comments": "", "processDefinitionNameOrId": "", "skipEntryCriteria": "true"}]}';
xhr.send(strBodyJson); 


var rText = myFunction(eval(xhr.responseText));

if(! rText || rText === 'undefined'){
   alert("Submitted successfully");
}
else{
  alert(rText);
}

function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out +=  arr[i].message;
    }
   return out;
}

}
```